# Symfony2 @UniqueEntity in custom Sonata Admin Class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, unique-constraint

This my Entities example code.

EntityOne.php

```
//....
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
//....

/**
 * EntityOne
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\EntityOneRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"entityTwo", "number"},
 *     errorPath="number",
 *     message="A entityTwo with this number already exists."
 * )
 */
class EntityOne
{

    //....

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityTwo", inversedBy="entityOne")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entitytwo_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $entityTwo;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="number", type="integer")
     * 
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $number;

    //....

}
```

EntityTwo.php

```
/**
 * EntityTwo
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\EntityTwoRepository")
 */
class EntityTwo
{

    //....

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityOne", mappedBy="entityTwo", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"number" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $entityOne;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="totals", type="integer")
     * 
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $totals;

    //....

}
```

I am using SonataAdminBundle with *regular* admin class of the entity everything works fine.

The problem with @UniqueEntity is in another place.
In a different admin class, create a record number of EntityOne, the number depends on the value of a field in EntityOne.

To do this, I do it as follows:

EntityTwoAdmin.php

```
class EntityTwoAdmin extends Admin {

    //....

    protected $formOptions = array(
        'cascade_validation' => true        
    );

    //....

    public function preUpdate($entityTwo) {

        $numTotals = $entityTwo->getTotals();
        $numEntityOneExist = $entityTwo->getEntityOne()->count();

        for ($i = $numEntityOneExist; $i <= $numTotals; $i++) {

            $entityOneNew = new \AppBundle\Entity\EntityOne;

            $entityOneNew->setNumber($i);

            $entityTwo->addEntityOne($entityOneNew);
        }

    }
}
```

Here records are created without considering the constraint validation.

I do not know what I may be missing, but certainly something I need to fix.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it, I am not clear whether it is the best way or do not follow the best practices of symfony.

I share here, for those who can help:

EntityTwoAdmin.php

```
public function preUpdate($entityTwo) {

    $numTotals = $entityTwo->getTotals();
    $numEntityOneExist = $entityTwo->getEntityOne()->count();

    for ($i = $numEntityOneExist; $i <= $numTotals; $i++) {

        $entityOneNew = new \AppBundle\Entity\EntityOne;
        $entityOneNew->setNumber($i);
        $entityOneNew->setEntityTwo($entityTwo);

        $validator = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('validator');
        $errors = $validator->validate($entityOneNew);

        if (count($errors) == 0) {

            $entityTwo->addEntityOne($entityOneNew);

        }
    }

}
```